How to use skmultilearn.iterative_train_test_split to split to test, val and test?
The goal is to split an imbalanced dataset to train, val and test sets in order to train a multilabel model.
Following this simple example from HuggingFace and the documentation it is clear to me how to split the data to test and train (90-10 ratio) skmultilearn.iterative_train_test_split from api :
train_idx, y_train, test_idx, test_val = iterative_train_test_split(x, y, test_size = 0.1) 
I want to test my model later, but not sure how to split to train, val and test (80-10-10) while still preserving the distributions of stratified splitting.
Thoughts so far -
Running it twice like here but then not sure if the qualities of the function preserved. also API is different from StratifiedShuffleSplit in sklearn so not sure how to do so.
